# Airflow: how to mark ExternalTaskSensor operator as Success after timeout

Tags: python, airflow

I have a dag `A`, which is waiting for some other operators in other dags `B` and `C` to download the data, and then performs come computations on it.

It for some operators in dags `B` and `C` it takes too long, I'd like to continue without "hanging" operators and use whatever data I received so far.

Thus, I have a timeout, and I'd like to **mark my `ExternalTaskSensor`s as Success after a given timeout.**
How can I do that?

```py
# dag A:

wait_for_task_1 = ExternalTaskSensor(
    task_id='wait_B_task_1',
    external_dag_id='B',
    external_task_id='task_1',
    dag=dag,
    timeout=(4 * 3600) # After 4 hours, I want to continue A "as is"
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is currently not possible but what you can do is set `trigger_rule='all_done'` on task that is directly dependent on `wait_for_task_1`.

Example:

```
wait_for_task_1 = ExternalTaskSensor(
    task_id='wait_B_task_1',
    external_dag_id='B',
    external_task_id='task_1',
    dag=dag,
    timeout=(4 * 3600) # After 4 hours, I want to continue A "as is"
)

task_2 = DummyOperator(task_id='task_2', trigger_rule='all_done', dag=dag)

wait_for_task_1 >> task_2
```

That will allow the downstream task to be run even though the task has failed.
The default `trigger_rule` for all tasks is `all_success`.

Docs: https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#trigger-rules